# Linq compare datetime values

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have `dateTime` value `start` and `finish` date. I compare it from old values. If it is exist i dont let to update.
Value properties in `entity` it is `int` and `client` it is `dateTime`. 
 `Linq` code is;

```
  public static bool IsWROExist(CRO cROne)
        {
            Entities entities = new Entities();
            int startDate = Convert.ToInt32(cROne.StartDate);
            int finishDate = Convert.ToInt32(cROne.FinishDate);

            return (from WRO in entities.WRO
                    where WRO.id != cROne.Id &&
                          (WRO.startDate == startDate &&
                              WRO.finishDate == finishDate )
                    select WRO).Any();
        }
```

I am getting this error : Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Why are you converting `DateTime` to `Int`?

Comment: Because in entity it is Int and my client side it is DateTime

Comment: What type is cROne.StartDate

Comment: What does the int represent? days? minutes? seconds?

Comment: What are `StartDate` and `FinishDate`? Is this where the Exception is being thrown (on `Convert.ToInt32`)? Are they actual `DateTime` instances or of type `string`? What are the values if they are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to convert the date time:

```
int n = int.Parse(date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

and then compare with the value.

!!warning: int may not hold the value fully. you might want to use long data type.

Comment: Thank you i solved it;
but i didnt add "mmss" because if i add it I am getting exception.

int n = int.Parse(date.ToString("yyyyMMddHH"));

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're not using the variables that contain the start and end date.

The following is what you should have

```
                     && (WRO.startDate == startDate &&
                          WRO.finishDate == finishDate )
```

Comment: You right i edit my comment. thnk u but my exception i think it is about my convert?

Answer (score 1):

You have added the `&&` twice:

```
 return (from WRO in entities.WRO
                where WRO.id != cROne.Id &&    <-------
            ------>      && (WRO.startDate == startDate &&
                          WRO.finishDate == finishDate )
                select WRO).Any();
```

Comment: Thank you I edit it. Sorry I am new here that's why I missed code

Comment: Does it fix your problem?

Comment: No problem is not about that I just forget to add it my post